# How do you use Tailwind animate classes with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

For example - add animate-ping upon new message from a web-socket.

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind `just-in-time` is likely to be the reason why you can't do that.

Basically, if `animate-ping` is not scraped in your files, adding it through Javascript or any other way later will simply not work, as the CSS file generated will not include `animate-ping`.

You should likely make your very own class in your CSS, even if it means using `@apply` directive of Tailwind. Adding Tailwind class later on in the DOM that were never parsed at build time will simply.. not works.

Comment: Thanks! I will stick to https://react-spring.dev/ for now. I thought it would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally show a class would be something like this:

```
function Notification() {
  const [isNotification, setIsNotification] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={` ${isNotification ? "animate-ping" : null} h-2 w-2 m-5 bg-sky-400 rounded-full`}></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It does not work or the animation is looped